# What is a slow clock oscillator embedded microprocessor (MPU)

Tags: microcontroller, oscillator, crystal, microprocessor

I am using [SAMA5D27C-D1G-CU](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MPU32/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/SAMA5D2-Series-Datasheet-ds60001476.pdf) in my design. In the signal description I can see that it has two oscillators.

Main oscillator and slow clock oscillator. Please see the image below.

I have couple of questions.

- What is the difference between main oscillator and slow clock oscillator.
- Why we need a main oscillator and slow clock oscillator?
- Will the IC work without slow clock oscillator?
- What is the purpose of slow clock oscillator?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without looking at the datasheet block diagrams, there is no exact answer in what are all the possible ways the clocks can be used, but pretty much every MCU with support for two external crystals are very similar, so I will give a general answer which applies to why many different MCUs have fast and slow crystal oscillators

1. Difference is the fast oscillator is intended for crystals that are for example in 1 to 25 MHz range. The slow clock oscillator is usually used with a 32 kHz crystal, hence the name XIN32 and XOUT32 for pins of your MCU. Some MCUs support slow oscillator speeds in some wider range, but some only support 32768 Hz crystal.
2. You might need two oscillators for many reasons. First reason is that the CPU itself runs from the main oscillator and an integrated real-time clock (RTC) runs from the 32 kHz oscillator. It means you can put the MCU into sleep mode which turns off the fast oscillator, or you can turn MCU main power off, and the 32 kHz crystal still runs from battey backup for timekeeping.
3. Usually the oscillators are optional, especially the 32 kHz oscillator. If you don't need it for anything there is no need to have it.
4. As explained already, it is most often used for battery backed up real time clock. Some MCUs allow or require using it for other purposes as well, usually related to saving power by running the MCU with the 32kHz clock, or putting the MCU into sleep mode and have the 32kHz clock running some low power standby peripherals that need to react to external events and wake up the MCU.